# Cloud Bigtable: when I filter by column, are my modify requests atomic?

Tags: python, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

In my Cloud Bigtable table, I have millions of requests per second. I get a unique row key and then I need to modify the row with an atomic mutation.

When I filter by column to get the key, will it be atomic for each request?

```
col1_filter = row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter(b'customerId')
label1_filter = row_filters.ValueRegexFilter('')
chain1 = row_filters.RowFilterChain(filters=[col1_filter, label1_filter])

partial_rows = table.read_rows(filter_=chain1)

for data in partial_rows:
    row_cond = table.row(data.cell[row_key])
    row_cond.set_cell(u'data', b'customerId', b'value', state=True)
    row_cond.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CheckAndMutateRow operations are atomic](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writes#conditional), BUT it is check and mutate **row** not rows. So the way you have this set up wont create the atomic operation.

You need to create a [conditional row](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/row.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row.ConditionalRow) object using the rowkey and your filter, supply the modification, then commit. Like so:

```
col1_filter = row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter(b'customerId')
label1_filter = row_filters.ValueRegexFilter('')
chain1 = row_filters.RowFilterChain(filters=[col1_filter, label1_filter])

partial_rows = table.read_rows()

for data in partial_rows:
    row_cond = table.row(data.cell[row_key], filter_=chain1) # Use filter here
    row_cond.set_cell(u'data', b'customerId', b'value', state=True)
    row_cond.commit()
```

So you would have to do a full table scan and apply the filter to each row. If you are applying that filter, you'd be doing a full scan already, so there shouldn't be performance differences. For best practices with Cloud Bigtable, you want to avoid full table scans. If this is a one time program you need to run that would be fine, otherwise you may want to figure out a different way to do this if you're going to be doing it regularly.

Note that we are [updating the API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8451) to be provide more clarity on the different kinds of mutations.